# How to I get rid of "unchecked due to erasure" warning when pattern matching

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, type-erasure, parser-combinators

Scala 2.8.1

I have implemented a very simple external DSL using parser/combinators for QA to write acceptance tests.

Recently I added the ability to loop over a set of expressions like so

```
sealed trait Expr

...
//insert other case classes extending 'Expr' here
...

case class Repetition(times: Int, expressions: List[Expr]) extends Expr

class TestFixtureParser(....) extends RegexParsers {
  val repeatParser: Parser[Expr] = (l("repeat") ~> number) ~ (l("{") ~> expressions <~ l("}")) ^^ {
    case (times: Int) ~ (exprs: List[Expr]) => {
      Repetition(times, exprs)
    }
  }

  private val expressions: Parser[List[Expr]] = (repeatParser | 
    /*insert other Parser[Expr]s '|' together here */ | verifyParser ).*

}
```

When building, I receive the warning `warning: non variable type-argument ... is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure` when pattern matching. I have tried extracting using the following as well.

```
  //Doesn't build with error
  /*
    error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x0$2) => x0$2 match {
      case $tilde((times @ _), (exprs @ _)) => Repetition(times, exprs)
    })
        r: ~[Int, List[Expr]] => {
  */
  val repeatParser: Parser[Expr] = (l("repeat") ~> number) ~ (l("{") ~> expressions <~ l("}")) ^^ {
    r: ~[Int, List[Expr]] => {
      case times ~ exprs =>
        Repetition(times, exprs)
    }
  }

  //Actually this does build without warning. 
  //I am unfortunately using intelliJ and it doesn't like it
  val repeatParser: Parser[Expr] = (l("repeat") ~> number) ~ (l("{") ~> expressions <~ l("}")) ^^ {
    repetitions: ~[Int, List[Expr]] => {
      val ~(times, exprs) = repetitions
      Repetition(times, exprs)
    }
  }

  //Builds but same warning
  val repeatParser: Parser[Expr] = (l("repeat") ~> number) ~ (l("{") ~> expressions <~ l("}")) ^^ {
    repetitions => {
      val ~(times: Int, exprs: List[Expr]) = repetitions
      Repetition(times, exprs)
    }
  }
```

Does anyone have any suggestions for extracting `exprs` in an elegant way without this warning? It does function as is. Should I just ignore it? I would hate to get into the habit of ignoring warnings.

Edit: Answer. This was actually what I tried first but then I added the types because the intelliJ scala plugin couldn't infer them.

```
  val repeatParser: Parser[Expr] = (l("repeat") ~> number) ~ (l("{") ~> expressions <~ l("}")) ^^ {
      case times ~ exprs =>
          Repetition(times, exprs)
  }
```

Comment: What I'm curious about is why your first example for "doesn't build" doesn't build ... I would think Scala would be able to infer the types in the case expression. What error do you get?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your syntax is not right for the first "doesn't build" example (it looks like you're returning a partial function rather than applying it, which isn't what you want). Try
writing:

```
val repeatParser: Parser[Expr] = (l("repeat") ~> number) ~ (l("{") ~> expressions <~ l("}")) ^^ {
    case times ~ exprs =>
        Repetition(times, exprs)
}
```

I'm afraid I can't test this because I don't have the rest of your code it
depends on, but this kind of construct usually works.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is the best, but here are alternatives for when that doesn't work:

```
r: ~[t1, t2] => {
  case times ~ exprs =>
    Repetition(times, exprs)
}
```

Above, `t1` and `t2` are *inferred*, and they might just be inferred to `Any`. Whatever they are inferred to, however, it is the best you can do with that syntax.

```
val ~(times: Int, exprs: List[t]) = repetitions
```

Here, because you are extracting the values, you can actually check for the types. You are not testing if you have a `~[Int,List[Int]]` -- you are testing if the *extracted values* have types `Int` and `List[t]`. Note that the warning you got came from the type parameter to `List`.

Comment: Yeah, I completely get the erasure thing. The only difference between what I had in my code and the accepted answer is that I have the explicit types. The problem is that I rely too much on the IntelliJ scala plugin for the time being. It complained with a red squiggly line that the types for ~ can not be inferred there. The compiler says otherwise. It was great for helping me to learn the language over the last 8 months or so, but as I use more advanced constructs, the refactoring tools and context help are beginning to stop working like they should.

Comment: @drstevens I'm not sure we are talking about the same thing. When I write `~[t1, t2]` I'm being very precise: the use of a lowercase type here indicates to the compiler that it should infer the types, and assign them to `t1` and `t2`.

Comment: You are right, we weren't talking about the same thing. I didn't know that the lower case type parameter has significance here. I need to understand this more. Thank you for replying with that.

Comment: @drstevens It took me more than two years to learn about it myself, it is pretty obscure. Note that _"here"_ refers to pattern matching. It won't work on `val` declarations either, unless it occurs inside a pattern (like `val Some(t: ~[t1, t2]) = ...`.